# Changing an Object's attributes also Affects Another Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

**Problem:** When I change the `points` of a polygon `poly2`, it also changes the `points` of another polygon `poly`!!

Why does changing one also change the other, and **how do we decouple them**?

```
console.log(poly.getPoints()[1].x);  // 100

// Make a change to `poly2`
poly2.setPoints(poly.getPoints());
poly2.getPoints()[1].x=200

console.log(poly.getPoints()[1].x);  // 200 (both poly and poly2 are affected!)
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8hFyv/

Comment: Please include the code in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
poly2.setPoints(poly.getPoints());
```

This is your problem. The points array is the very same object.

Since you have arrays in your array, the `slice(0)` trick won't work, you need deep copy.

Fortunately, you're using jQuery, which has a method to do it.

Replace the above line with:

```
poly2.setPoints($.extend(true, [], poly.getPoints()));
```

Comment: In a way. We'd rather say it returns an object reference, as JavaScript doesn't have pointers as a primitive type you can operate on. But all objects behave this way. Consider: `a = {}; b = a; a.x = 3; console.log(b.x)` will print 3 - because `b = a` makes `b` a reference to the same object that `a` refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Your poly and poly2 object are referencing the same array of points when you do this:

```
poly2.setPoints(poly.getPoints());
```

Change it to this:

```
poly2.setPoints([0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100]);
```

Comment: I need to set `poly2` by passing into `poly.setPoints()` an array with the exact same values returned by `poly.getPoints()`. It may sound really simple, but how do I do this?

Comment: Call poly.getPoints().slice() for a copy of the array (instead of a copy of the reference to the array)

Comment: `slice` won't work, as it is too shallow - `getPoints()` returns an array of objects, not the original array.

Answer (score 1):

To clone the points, vs. sharing them between polygons, you'll need to create new objects for each yourself.

You can do this with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
poly2.setPoints(poly.getPoints().map(function (p) {
    return { x: p.x, y: p.y };
}));
```

Or, with [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
poly2.setPoints($.map(poly.getPoints(), function (p) {
    return { x: p.x, y: p.y };
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct in assessing the problem, but there's another way you can solve it: "clone" the points array when you set it.  In other words:

```
poly2.setPoints(poly.getPoints().slice());
```

If for some reason `getPoints()` returns something other than an array, you'll need a different cloning approach (eg. the one that axel.michel suggested), but since I think it does that should work for you.

Comment: `console.log(poly.getPoints())` in Chrome dev tools tells me its an Array, returning `[0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100]`! So Chrome is wrong?

Comment: It is an array. As I note elsewhere, `.slice()` doesn't work because it is an array two levels deep - `.slice()` will only perform the shallow copy, but will still share the mini-objects `{ x: ..., y: ... }` that hold the individual coordinates.

Comment: @Nyxynyx: This is what I get: `[{"x":0,"y":0},{"x":100,"y":0},{"x":100,"y":100},{"x":0,"y":100}]`. I'm not getting the flat array as you say. Can you check again?

Comment: Yup I get the same as you did. I guess objects within arrays behave the same way as you explained in your answer's comment. Something I need to get my head around, for some strange reason I didnt encounter this problem after doing javascript/jquery/backbone/nodejs for quite some time...

Comment: First, quick terminology point: that is a "flat" array, as it doesn't contain any sub-arrays.  However, it does contain objects, and those won't get cloned when you clone the array, so you'll have to clone them manually.  Other answerers have provided other alternatives, and major libraries like jQuery and Underscore also have clone methods you can use.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that poly.getPoints is a set of Kinetic Pointer Objects, to get rid of it, try the following:

```
poly2.setPoints(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(poly.getPoints())));
```